# How to scroll/swipe part of the page?

Tags: appium-android

I have to horizontaly scroll that part of page (it's moveable left and right).

[printscreen of the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXjsG.jpg)

How to do that?

I tried to capture some region of page and swipe it, but IDE just executing code with 0. Then I tried to find that actual element and move it, but still nothing. In real app you just tap on the screen and move that part left or right.

Answer (score 0):

Scrolling is different from swiping. When you scroll the page you don't release your finger from the screen but in scrolling, you release your finger and the speed of page movement is more controllable.

**So for scrolling try:**

```
String scrollViewContainer_finder = "new UiSelector().resourceIdMatches(\".*id/Your_ID\")"; // Your_ID=element resource-id
    String neededElement_finder = "new UiSelector().text(\"Your_Text\")";
    WebElement abc = driver.findElement(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(" + scrollViewContainer_finder + ")" +
            ".scrollIntoView(" + neededElement_finder + ")"));
```

Replace Your-Text with any word on the screen you are looking for. For other elements options look [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/uiautomator/UiSelector).

**for swiping:**

Method:

```
    public void swipe(int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY, int msDuration) {
    TouchAction touchAction = new TouchAction((PerformsTouchActions) driver);
    touchAction.press(PointOption.point(startX, startY))
            .waitAction(WaitOptions.waitOptions(Duration.ofMillis(msDuration)))
            .moveTo(PointOption.point(endX, endY))
            .release();
```

Example Usage:

```
swipe(600, 1750, 600, 400, 2000);
```

Please be noted that:

1. To find the exact Start and End x,y: Turn on "Show pointer location" from the "Developer Options" of device/emulator and then you can find the exact x,y of touching anywhere of the screen.
2. For better testing, you can turn off these options from the Developer Options:
   *Window animation scale / 
   Transition animation scale / 
   Animator duration scale /*
3. I found that the normal "msDuration" is about 2000ms.
4. I strongly recommend swiping method for any usage of scrolling/swiping.